# Destroy UIView in init if condition isn't met

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to make a custom alert view that checks to see if a condition is true, and if so it builds itself and attaches itself to the window. However, if this condition is not true, I just want the view to deallocate itself, preferably in the `init` method. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: If the condition isn't met then no need to create alert view. Check the condition before creating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is better to follow SOLID principles in coding.

Singularity is an important thing.One function is supposed to do a single thing not many dependencies.

So Keep the view just to show the custom alert.And the check for showing must be done outside such that

```
//Please note this is the algorithm not the exact code in Obj-C.
if(condition==True)
{
//Display customView
}
else
{
//Do nothing
}
```

Comment: The Objective-C convention is to use `YES/NO` instead of `True/False`. The `== TRUE` is also redundant as `condition` is already a boolean value.

Comment: @Paul.s :Correct.but what i write here is the algorithm not the Obj-C Code :)

Comment: The issue with this logic is that this algorithm is executable and you can guarantee a new programmer will copy and paste it exactly - not knowing any better - therefore this is not exemplary and could lead to this style/pattern being followed throughout a project - it's amazing how authoritive an answer on SO can seem, especially if it has up votes and has been accepted